# How can work output on python?

Tags: python, join, output

I want made a script for storage capacity modify but I have a some problem.

My script has the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
    mod_f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
TypeError: sequence item 3: expected string, float found
```

Below is my script.

```
mod_f = open("mod_c_vol_size.txt", 'w')
mod_f.write("Vserver,Volume,Aggregate,Total,Avail,Node,SaveA,SaveD,SaveC,Snap,Tused\n")
unit = ['TB', 'GB', 'MB', 'KB', 'B']
with open("find_c_vol_modify.txt", "r") as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
                if len(line.strip()) != 0:
                        line = line.split(',')
                        out = []
                        for l in line[3:5] + line[6:11]:
                                l = l.replace('\n','')
                                try:
                                        ind = [unit[i] in l for i in range(5)].index(True)
                                except ValueError:
                                        print('please check script')

                                val = str(l.split(unit[ind])[0])
                                out.append(float(val)/1024**ind)
                        line = line[0:3] + out[:-5] + line[5:6] + out[2:]
                        print (line)
mod_f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
mod_f.close()
```

Error is at line `mod_f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')`

below is my input text file.

```
Vserver,Volume,Aggregate,Total,Avail,Node,SaveA,SaveD,SaveC,Snap,Tused
XXXX,YYYY,Node1_aggr1,1TB,1023GB,FAS8040-ZZZZ,0B,0B,0B,0B,177.7MB
XXXX,ZZZZ,Node1_aggr1,3TB,3.00TB,FAS8040-ZZZZ,0B,0B,0B,0B,1.60GB
XXXX,CCCC,Node1_aggr1,1TB,907.9GB,FAS8040-ZZZZ,0B,0B,0B,0B,116.1GB
XXXX,VVVV,Node1_aggr1,200GB,200.0GB,FAS8040-ZZZZ,0B,0B,0B,0B,6.25MB
```

below is expected output file.

```
['XXXX', 'YYYY', 'Node1_aggr1', 1.0, 0.9990234375, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00016946792602539061]
['XXXX', 'ZZZZ', 'Node1_aggr1', 3.0, 3.0, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0015625]
['XXXX', 'CCCC', 'Node1_aggr1', 1.0, 0.88662109375, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.11337890625]
['XXXX', 'VVVV', 'Node1_aggr1', 0.1953125, 0.1953125, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.9604644775390625e-06]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

`out.append(float(val)/1024**ind)`

you are appending a `float` type to the list, which is not a string.

In order to use `.join(list)`, the `list` needs to be composed of strings only.

You can fix this by type casting what you are going to append as a string first:

`out.append(str(float(val)/1024**ind))`

Answer (score 1):

`expected string, float found` convert it to string

```
....
line = [str(x) for x in line]        
print(','.join(line) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

The fourth item in each `line` list is a `float` element that you computed: `1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.1953125` (as are later elements).  `join` works only on strings.  You'll need to convert the `float` items to `string` somewhere.  Perhaps

```
out.append(str(float(val)/1024**ind))
```

or some generality just before you write

```
line = [str(item) for item in line]
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation had problem and you need to use `str(line)` when writing to file.

You do not need `mod_f.write(','.join(line) + '\n')` instead you can use `mod_f.write(str(line) + '\n')`

Please check `NOTE:` below in my solution regarding usage of `join` in your case.

```
mod_f = open("mod_c_vol_size.txt", 'w')
mod_f.write("Vserver,Volume,Aggregate,Total,Avail,Node,SaveA,SaveD,SaveC,Snap,Tused\n")
unit = ['TB', 'GB', 'MB', 'KB', 'B']
with open("find_c_vol_modify.txt", "r") as f:
    next(f)
    for line in f:
        if len(line.strip()) != 0:
            line = line.split(',')
            out = []
            for l in line[3:5] + line[6:11]:
                l = l.replace('\n','')
                try:
                    ind = [unit[i] in l for i in range(5)].index(True)
                except ValueError:
                    print('please check script')
                val = str(l.split(unit[ind])[0])
                out.append(float(val)/1024**ind)
            line = line[0:3] + out[:-5] + line[5:6] + out[2:]
            print (line)
            mod_f.write(str(line) + '\n')
mod_f.close()
```

Sample Run

```
['XXXX', 'YYYY', 'Node1_aggr1', 1.0, 0.9990234375, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.00016946792602539061]
['XXXX', 'ZZZZ', 'Node1_aggr1', 3.0, 3.0, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0015625]
['XXXX', 'CCCC', 'Node1_aggr1', 1.0, 0.88662109375, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.11337890625]
['XXXX', 'VVVV', 'Node1_aggr1', 0.1953125, 0.1953125, 'FAS8040-ZZZZ', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.9604644775390625e-06]
```

Output in file

[image]

`NOTE:` If you use `join` while writing to file then output on screen would be good but check the file, the file will have unexpected output like below

[image]